# Авторизация пользователя на разных сайтах

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, oracle, авторизация

Изначально имелся проект, написанный на Asp.NET'e с базой Oracle, к которому решили добавить ещё одно приложение. Второе приложение было куплено. Написано оно на PHP, использует базу MySQL.

Теперь требуется совместить сайты, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на одном сайте переходило на второй, при этом без ввода пароля и логина авторизация происходила автоматически, а также реализовать алгоритм, который при регистрации на одном сайте автоматически добавит этого пользователя ко второму сайту.

Вот варианты, которые созрели в моём неопытном джуновском мозгу:

1) Переписать одно из приложений под другую БД, но тут возникает проблема с незнанием PHP, а смена БД в основном проекте также достаточно проблематична.

2) Создание триггера в самой БД Oracle или MySQL, чтобы при Insert'e Email и Hash отправлялся SQL-запросом прямо в другую БД. Но я не уверен безопасно ли это, и реализуемо ли это вообще.

3) Подключение двух БД с каждому из проектов но, насколько я понимаю, вариант очень кривой. Да и PHP проблемы со знанием PHP дадут знать о себе.

4) В БД хранится логин и пароль от пользователя. Логин находится в нормальном виде, а пароль зашифрован. Я думал над тем, чтобы как-то передавать именно этот Hash из БД, чтобы второй сайт его нормально воспринял и авторизовал меня. Но возникает проблема с тем, что даже при одинаковом пароле этот Hash различается.

Хотелось бы услышать Ваши вариант реализации решения данной проблемы, либо ответ какой из моих вариантов является наиболее безопасным, простым и быстрым. реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне часто приходилось решать подобные задачи на PHP в разных случаях.

Например, когда приложение допускает расширение авторизации - например, [движок phpbb умеет](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150872/) подобное. Или когда приходилось вклиниваться внутрь кем-то написанного приложения, когда приходилось самостоятельно разбираться в самописном роутинге и механизмах аутентификации. И даже когда были требования не лазить в ядро приложения, а дописывать плагин сбоку.

Давайте по факту: все ваши предложения крутятся на уровне БД. Вставлять записи, править записи, триггеры... Вы почему-то упорно не хотите работать с кодом приложений - а зря, это самое правильное направление. Возможно, вас останавливает то, что вы не знаете PHP -- в общем-то нужно предоставить руководству аргменты за то, чтобы вам если не полноценного разработчика взяли, так фрилансера на некоторое время. Либо уж -- учите PHP и просите надбавку за дополнительные обязанности, раз вам обслуживать теперь эту систему из двух сайтов.

Похоже, из-за этой нехватки ресурсов программистов вы ищете способы через базы, полагая, что это "проще". Дальше я буду говорить о том, как "правильно", полагая, что ресурсы у вас всё же ЕСТЬ.

Каким бы путём шёл я. На стороне PHP написал бы небольшую страничку, которая принимает набор гет-параметров (логин, пароль, емейл) и вызывает код PHP-приложения, которое отвечает за создание пользователя. И, когда на сайте который на c# написан наступает событие создания пользователя -- отправлял бы запрос на создание аналогичного пользователя. Аналогично и в обратную сторону: при создании пользователя на сайте PHP код авторизации дополнил бы отправкой POST-запроса на специальную страницу другого сайта.

Это самый простой вариант.

Варианты с таблицами SQL могут не сработать по двум причинам:

- вы можете не угадать полностью логику приложения, которую оно выполняет при создании пользователя
- вы не восстановите пароль по хешу и соли (если только приложение не написано криво, потому что вообще-то хеширование с солью как раз призвано сохранить пароль в тайне)

Кроме того, как-то с коллегой приходилось реализовывать сложный вариант межсайтовой авторизции между c# и php. Пароли на сайтах были разные, какие -- никто из сайтов не знал, просто был создан некоторый собственный протокол (жалкий обрубок OAuth, им и вдохновлялись, показывать не просите: во-первых, NDA, во-вторых, самому стыдно за кривизну из-за спешки, в-третьих, я ещё не видел заключение наших безопасников по части того, как мы токены генерили). Там было принято допущение, что если пользователь авторизован на одном сайте - то его можно автоматом авторизовать и на другом. Главное - лишь бы логины совпадали, остальную работу делал протокол из трёх страничек. Можете попоробовать такую же штуку сделать, если что -- вдохновляйтесь OAuth.